# Not able to login to Gmail from browser

Tags: connection-issues

I have my android phone connected to Wifi. When I open youtube in browser it opens perfectly and other sites as well but I can't open Gmail, facebook etc "in browser". The message says that the requested page might be temporarily down or moved to a new web address. Google play also isn't working. I  cleared data and cache from the browser but it didn't work. Then I went on to factory reset the phone but still no hope. If anybody could help..please.

Comment: Does the Wi-Fi network that you use block social media sites and Email? Have you tried another (home) Wi-Fi connection?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the browser or anything else, if you try to connect via the gprs (mobile network) it won't block. And to make it pretty sure, you can try to download Opera Mini v7. Then you will be able to see that it will load pages even when they are blocked.

ISPs block site, as per orders of govt. or on their own. The issue is mainly because of that! But still, you might try out Opera Mini, and check if the site is working for you or not. If Opera Mini is working, then their is some issue with the connection.

If the problem persists, you might try to use some VPN. That's the only way to get around when the ISP is blocking some sites.